# Java, Named Bean, wildcard?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, runtime, classloader

We need to retrieve multiple class-instances during runtime, withoud manually maintaining a list of all available Types.

Possible Approaches:

- Retrieve an instance of each type *annotated* with `@xy`
- Retrieve an instance of each type *implementing* the interface `iXY`
- Retrieve an instance of each type, *named* like `xy%`

Requirements:

- Instance should be container managed. (CDI)
- If possible, no reflection

What I tried:

**Annotations**, but it seems that the only way of reading annotations during runtime is reflection. Also this would return me the `class-type` of which I would need to create instances. (But unmanaged then)

Same for interface implementations.

The perfect way would be to evaluate an el-expression, containing a wildcard:

```
List<IMyInterface> instances = evaluateExpression("#{commonNameStart*}");
```

of couse, all the Names could be maintained somewhere in a properties file - but if possible I would like avoid that.

Basically I need something like the Hibernate-Entity-Scanner for custom Annotations.

Is there a nice way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can generally be achieved by injecting the interface `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`, appropriately parameterized. At least the two first suggested approaches are possible. Some template pseudo-code is:

```
@Inject @Foo @Bar private Instance<Xxxx> myVariable;
```

**Explanation of the code above:**

1. *Retrieve an instance of each type annotated with `@xy`*: `@xy` should be a *qualifier* (see specs, but it is really as simple as follows):

   ```
   @Qualifier
   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   @Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
   public @interface XY {

   }
   ```

   In which case the template code would be:

   ```
   @Inject @XY private Instance<Object> myVariable;
   ```

   Meaning roughly "get all the CDI beans having the `@XY` qualifier, disregarding actual type (the `<Object>`)".
2. *Retrieve an instance of each type implementing the interface iXY*: Easier:

   ```
   public interface XY { ... }
   ```

   Injection:

   ```
   @Inject private Instance<XY> myVariable;
   ```
3. *Retrieve an instance of each type, named like `xy%`*: This *could* be possible, I think the implementation would be quite awkward. I will not go into this.

Anyway, `Instance` is an `Iterable` of its type parameter (`Object` in the first case, `XY` in the second), so in your code you can enumerate the beans matching your criteria as simple as:

```
for( Object o : myVariable ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this day - looks promising :)

Comment: Tested the interface based injection - works like a charm :-)